# Paypal + codeigniter - notify_url

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am integrating paypal payment feature in my codeigniter app. The notify URL which I pass as a form param to paypal is successfully called, but the time it takes for paypal to call it is about 15-20 mins. Is that normal ? It takes me too much time to debug and test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is way out.
I was facing the same problem and ci merchant library help me out 
there is a link to library 
http://tutsnare.com/integrate-paypal-using-ci-merchant-in-codeigniter/
https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant.php
if any help pin me 
enjoy